# Spring cloud data flow server cloud not taking the correct data source ip passed as parameter

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I'm trying to run `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.5.1` using the following command:

> java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
>   --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.103:3306/scdf --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password=12345 --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --spring.rabbitmq.host=192.168.0.103 --spring.rabbitmq.port=5672 --spring.rabbitmq.username=admin --spring.rabbitmq.password=admin

But after run, I get following error which unfortunately try to connect `192.168.0.102` which is my host PC IP instead of `192.168.0.103` which is the IP of my VM:

```
Spring Cloud Data Flow Local Server  (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2018-12-01 16:45:42.023  INFO 615 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2018-12-01 16:45:42.135  WARN 615 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2018-12-01 16:45:42.137  INFO 615 --- [           main] o.s.c.d.s.local.LocalDataFlowServer      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-01 16:45:43.463  INFO 615 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-12-01 16:45:43.487  INFO 615 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-12-01 16:45:43.625  INFO 615 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2018-12-01 16:45:44.017  INFO 615 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0e79f456-ca92-3486-8c38-277da0a72d84
2018-12-01 16:45:45.229  INFO 615 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9393 (http)
2018-12-01 16:45:45.259  INFO 615 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-01 16:45:45.260  INFO 615 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-12-01 16:45:45.362  INFO 615 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-01 16:45:46.025  INFO 615 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-12-01 16:45:47.131 ERROR 615 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.102' (using password: NO)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:135) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:101) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwException(ExceptionMapper.java:91) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:109) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.5.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:367) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:196) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:325) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:365) [spring-jdbc-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dad57b0f.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$7(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dad57b0f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4f7adc4d.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dad57b0f.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.13.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.13.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.17.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.17.RELEASE]
```